# PowerShell Extract from zip file 17 folders deep

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I have a zip file that is automatically created and I can't change the number of folders within it.

I am trying to extract all the contents from a folder that is 17 folders deep within the zip file. The issue is that the name of the folders can change.

I started to use 7Zip to extract another zip folder and that works fine:

```
$zipExe = join-path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} '7-zip\7z.exe'
if (-not (test-path $zipExe)) {
    $zipExe = join-path ${env:ProgramW6432} '7-zip\7z.exe'
    if (-not (test-path $zipExe)) {
         '7-zip does not exist on this system.'
    }
}
set-alias zip "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
zip x $WebDeployFolder -o \$WebDeployTempFolder
```

Is there a way to extract the content in the folder that is 17 folders deep within the zip file?

Comment: I am missing the question or the issue you are facing : can you edit your question so it clearly states the problem you are facing?

Comment: @bluuf done. Added So my question is: Is there a way to extract the content in the folder that is 17 folders deep within the zip file.

Comment: @bluuf My Answer is: Yes. Please clarify your question. What is the specific problem? Did you try ot on your own? Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: I suppose you're running into max path length issues on Windows with Powershell's native functions?

Comment: @jessehouwing No i am just not sure how to write it in powershell. So do I do somthing like StartFolder\*\*\*\* etc?

Comment: Did you try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 7Zip's listing function to get the contents of the file. Then you can parse that output, looking for the folder with 17 levels and use that path to extract the contents.

Below is an chunk of code which does just that.

```
$7zip = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$archiveFile = "C:\Temp\Archive.zip"
$extractPath = "C:\Temp"
$archiveLevel = 17

# Get contents list from zip file
$zipContents = & $7zip l $archiveFile

# Filter contents for only folders, described as "D" in Attr column
$contents = $zipContents | Where-Object { $_ -match "\sD(\.|[A-Z]){4}\s"}

# Get line where the folder level defined in $archiveLevel is present
$folderLine = $contents | Where-Object { ($_ -split "\\").Count -eq ($archiveLevel) }

# Get the folder path from line
$folderPath = $folderLine -split "\s" | Where-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -Last 1

# Extract the folder to the desired path. This includes the entire folder tree but only the contents of the desired folder level
Start-Process $7zip -ArgumentList "x $archiveFile","-o$extractPath","$folderPath" -Wait

# Move the contents of the desired level to the top of the path
Move-Item (Join-Path $extractPath $folderPath) -Destination $extractPath

# Remove the remaining empty folder tree
Remove-Item (Join-Path $extractPath ($folderPath -split "\\" | Select-Object -First 1)) -Recurse
```

There are a couple of caveats in the code. 
I couldn't find a way to extract just the folder without the full path/parensts. So that is cleaned up in the end. But note that the parent folders do not contain any other files or folders. 
Also, I had to use "Start-Process" at the end or 7Zip would break the variable input.

You will probably have to change it all a bit depending on your ZIP file structure, but it should get you going.

Comment: This works up to the point where it is Move-Item (Join-Path $extractPath$folderPath) -Destination $extractPath I am getting an Invalid Path error, the path is correct though.

Comment: I made an artificial test locally and it worked for me, but there could absolutely be some differences in your environment. Are you remembering to update the paths in the top? Can you supply the exact error message?

Comment: Yes I have changed the paths, I should add these are network paths. 
Error:
Invalid Path: Invalid Path: '\\MachineName\shared\GDistribute\Test\QA\WebsiteName\CodeName.Web\Content\R_C\GO47_1\DATA01\2\CodeName\BuildName\Sources\src\DIR\31x\Source\CodeName.Web\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp'.
At line:22 char:1
+ Move-Item (Join-Path $extractPath $folderPath) -Destination $extractPath
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveItemDynamicParametersProviderException

Comment: I dont see a reason why that shouldnt work, but it might be a provider issue. Try changing the Move-Item item line to this: 
Move-Item "filesystem::$(Join-Path $extractPath $folderPath)" -Destination "filesystem::$extractPath"